# Form in Spring with several buttons (save, delete, search, update), how to show searched items in the form

Tags: spring, forms

I have a POST form with 4 buttoms (save, delete, search, update) in a jsp and a controller.

The methods saving, updating and deleting in the controller work fine:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/myPage.htm",params = "delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void delete(HttpServletRequest request) {
//Construct item to save
this.itemService.deleteItem(item);
}
```

But the problem is the search method. I have tried several options:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/myPage.htm",params = "search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView search(@RequestParam(value="e1", required=false) String calle,
@RequestParam(value="e2", required=false) String e1, 
@RequestParam(value="e3", required=false) String e2,
@RequestParam(value="e3", required=false) String e3, 
HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response
){
//convert e2 to Integer
//construct the ModelAndView with the list the items
...}
```

The returning page is the same in all the cases, but in the search case, the form (the only form) elements are completed with the information from the list of items.

The point is that I get the error:request method 'get' not supported.

Any help?

Thank you very much in advance!

---

If I do that change to Gest, I get the error:
    [http-nio-8080-exec-3] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver  - Handler execution resulted in exception: Parameter conditions "search" not met for actual request parameters: (I do not get anything more in the error logs)

My method in the controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/myPage.htm",params = "search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView search(@RequestParam(value="e1", required=false) String e1, @RequestParam(value="e2", required=false) String e2, @RequestParam(value="e3", required=false) String e3, @RequestParam(value="e4", required=false) String e4, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){

//convert e2 to Integer
myModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();
List<Item> items= this.itemService.getItems(e1,e2b,e3,e4);
myModel.put("items", items);

} catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
return new ModelAndView("item", "model", myModel);
}
}
```

In the jsp I have:

```
<form:form method="post" action="MyPage.htm">
E1: <input name="e1" size="30"></input>
E2: <input name="e2" size="30"></input>
E3: <input name="e3" size="30"></input>
E4: <input name="e4" size="30"></input>
<button type="submit" name="save" style="width: 100px;"><span>Save</span></button>
<button type="submit" name="delete" style="width: 100px;"><span>Delete</span></button>
<button type="submit" name="update" style="width: 100px;"><span>Update</span></button>
<button type="submit" name="search" style="width: 100px;"><span>Search</span></button>
```

And, right now (just to try the code):

```
<c:forEach items="${model.items}" var="item">
    <c:out value="${item.getData()}" />
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: What is exactly the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/myPage.htm",params = "search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

To

```
@RequestMapping(value="/myPage.htm",params = "search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```